Count the result of Measure
I have below data, here 'Freight Code', and 'Amount(Sum of Amount)' are the table column and 'AmountFrth' and 'AFrPF' are measures created. Now I want to create the bar chart based out of it, where it will count the pass, fail and NA counts. I have the different table having only one column with 'Pass, Fail and NA' as values, to use on X Axis for bar chart.
Data: This is the table visual.
Please check the data here :

Here is logic of measures
AmountFrth = 
SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    SELECTEDVALUE('Data'[Freight Code]) = "C", 
    SUM(Data[Amount]) * 3,
    SELECTEDVALUE('Data'[Freight Code]) = "CD", 
    SUM(Data[Amount]) * 5,
    SELECTEDVALUE('Data'[Freight Code]) = "CT",
    SUM(Data[Amount]) * 7,
    SELECTEDVALUE('Data'[Freight Code]) = "DDP", 
    SUM(Data[Amount]) * 8,
    SELECTEDVALUE('Data'[Freight Code]) = "PP", 
    SUM(Data[Amount]) * 6,
    value(0) 
)

AFrPF = IF([AmountFrth] <150000 , "NA", if([AmountFrth] >=150000 && [AmountFrth] <200000, "Fail", if([AmountFrth] >=200000,"Pass", "")))

Data Fact:
1. Table has only these freight codes, so there are multiple record with one freight code in table.
2.No any other filters applied on table visual
3. I have another table called 'Table' and 'Value' as column name which has only 'Pass, Fail and NA records'
Feel free to ask any doubts.
I tried using counting the Pass, Fail and NA records but it is taking the whole dataset into account. so I expect as per the table visual 2 Pass records, 2 Fail records and 2 NA records.
I tried below Measure:
PassFailCount =
SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[Value]) = "Pass", 
    CALCULATE(
        COUNTROWS(Data),
        FILTER('Data', Data[AFrPF]="Pass")
    ),
    SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[Value]) = "Fail", 
    CALCULATE(
        COUNTROWS(Data),
        FILTER('Data', Data[AFrPF]="Fail")
    ),
    SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[Value]) = "NA",
    CALCULATE(
        COUNTROWS(Data),
       FILTER('Data', Data[AFrPF]="NA")
    ),  
    BLANK() 
)

But it is taking whole data set into account and as per Pass/Fail logic all records it is returning count of 'NA' which is not correct.

Can you provide the relationships between your tables ?

There is no relationship between Table 'Table' and Table 'Data'. 'Table' has only one column which will have the 'Pass, Fail and NA' records, which I think we can use on X axis for bar chart.

If you're trying to put a measure on anything other than VALUES (well, in Excel speak)... then it will fail. you can't.
if you really want a measure on a row/column in a matrix, then you'd have to create a calculated column and maybe tweak the measure to get it to work.

Can you please explain what I can do here, to get it work? Can we really able to write the PassFailCount measure that will take only that dataset(Table visual) to count the records for pass/fail ?

If you have a proper star schema you can. If you have one big blob of a table, you can't.
Calling a table "Table" is a horrible practice. You want whoever you give it to to understand what you're modeling.
